# PHP multisort the same item twice

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I have a simple luggage pick-up and return administration tool in PHP.
It generates a list for all luggage that arrives and when it will be picked up.

What I do is I run through the database to load all bookings for that specific day.

**Example**

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `luggage_requests` WHERE 
`request_start`='".date("Y-m-d")."' 
OR 
`request_end`='".date("Y-m-d")."'");
```

Then I load all bookings out of this result into an array.

**Example**

```
        $requests[] = $row["request_id"];
```

And I also load the times that the client comes to drop off or pick up their luggage.

**Example**

```
        ///######## DETERMINE THE IN OUT STATE
    if($row["request_start" == date("Y-m-d")){
        ///######## ASSIGN THE CORRECT TIME
        $request_times[] = (int)str_replace(":", "", $row["request_time1"]);
    }
    ///######## 
    elseif($row["request_eind"] == date("Y-m-d" ){
        ///######## ASSIGN THE CORRECT TIME
        $request_times[] = (int)str_replace(":", "", $row["request_time2"]);
    }
```

This list is sorted at the hand of the time that the clients drop off or pick up their luggage, which I do with *array_multisort*.

Generally the luggage will be picked up two or three days later.

However in some occasions it will be picked up again the same day at a later time.
The problem with my code construction is that the system will show the same booking only once.

And if clients return the same day. It will only show the moment the client comes to drop off his or her luggage. But not the time he or she comes to pick it up.

I am absolutely clueless how to do solve this at any nice and clean way.

Because I cannot load the same variable twice and then sort logically.
But I am ever more running into this problem.

Would anyone know how to solve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Below the full code:

```
<?php

///######## QUERY TO PLACE ALL ITEMS INTO AN ARRAY
$inout_parse_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `luggage_requests` WHERE `request_start`='".date("Y-m-d")."' OR `request_end`='".date("Y-m-d")."'") or die(mysql_error());            
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($inout_parse_query)) {
    ///######## IF THE REQUEST HAS NOT BEEN SAVED ALREADY
    if(!in_array($row["request_id"], $requests)){
        ///######## SAVING ALL IDS INTO AN ARRAY
        $requests[] = $row["request_id"];
        ///######## DETERMINE THE IN OUT STATE
        if($row["request_start" == date("Y-m-d")){
            ///######## ASSIGN THE CORRECT TIME
            $request_times[] = (int)str_replace(":", "", $row["request_time1"]);
        }
        ///######## 
        elseif($row["request_eind"] == date("Y-m-d" ){
            ///######## ASSIGN THE CORRECT TIME
            $request_times[] = (int)str_replace(":", "", $row["request_time2"]);
        }
    }
}

///######## SORT THE ARRAYS AT THE HAND OF THE TIME
array_multisort($request_times, $requests);

?>
```

Super!! Thanks for the reply!! I do not understand all of what your solution is. But 1st it works! Tried it in a small testing environment! And it works.

2nd I have some new stuff to learn and your solution gives me a good start to learn further. Thanks a million!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!in_array($row["request_id"], $requests))
```

Is the line that's messing you up.  There are instances when you need a request to be saved twice - once for the drop off and once for the pickup.

```
$resultSet = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($inout_parse_query)) 
{
  if ( $row["request_start"] == date('Y-m-d') ) 
  {  
    $row["sortby"] = $row["request_time1"];  
    $resultSet[] = $row;  
  }
  if ( $row["request_eind"] == date('Y-m-d') ) 
  {  
    $row["sortby"] = $row["request_time2"];  
    $resultSet[] = $row;  
  }
}
usort($resultSet,'sortluggage');

function sortluggage($a, $b)
{
  if ($a["sortby"] == $b["sortby"]) {  return 0;  }
  return ($a["sortby"] < $b["sortby"]) ? -1 : 1;
}
```